# How do you call this sound over the phone when you are calling someone, but they don't reply?

Tags: word-choice

How do you call this sound over the phone when you are calling someone, but they don't reply. Can the word *beep* used? For examlpe:

> I was trying to put through to Mike, but I heard only a series of **beeps**.

Comment: Note: we would say "they don't answer" rather than "they don't reply".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word used to describe the different *sounds* made by telephones is "*tones*".

When making an outgoing call, the sound you hear while it rings at the other end is called *the ringing tone* (or sometimes the *ringback* tone).

The other different tones you hear are *the engaged tone*, or *the busy tone* (when the person you are calling is already on a call); and *the dialling tone* (when you first pick up the receiver, before you begin to dial).

Comment: In UK 'ring tone' is common, although this is sometimes used to refer to the sound a mobile phone makes when an incoming call is received.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Good point about mobile phones, but I don't ever recall "ring tone" being used before mobiles. I was born in the UK in the 1970s.